# Ignored Tags get randomly concateneted

Tags: bug, status-norepro

On the prefs-tab, when I input tags to be ignored, they appear on the page instantly and look fine, but the POST to actually save them to the server concatenates them sometimes.

**I can reproduce the bug in Firefox and Google on Win XP, both when I type a tag in by hand and when I click on one of the autocomplete-suggestions.**

Two screenshots of the problem, captured in firebug:

here the last two tags, `installer` and `c` are combined to `installerc`

[screenshot of firebug: shows that POST sends different tags than shown on page http://www.users.fh-salzburg.ac.at/~bjelline/tagging-error.png](http://www.users.fh-salzburg.ac.at/~bjelline/tagging-error.png)

And this concatenated tag really get's stored and displayed when I load the page the next time

[screenshot of garbled tags http://www.users.fh-salzburg.ac.at/~bjelline/tagging-error-2.png](http://www.users.fh-salzburg.ac.at/~bjelline/tagging-error-2.png)

Comment: When you go back into your preferences, does it show them being concatenated?

Comment: How did you input them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprits: my "HUAWEI Mobile Connect" plus my mobile provider.

They do strange things to the javascript: strip out whitespace and insert external javascript into the html-page.  they must be overdoing the thing with the whitespace.

This problem could be avoided if you used any other character than space to separate the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a second -- are you reporting an actual BUG or just something you saw that "looked weird" in firebug? In other words, **are the tags actually incorrect after being saved, or not?**

Firebug has its own peculiarities; there was a time when running Firebug basically broke SO completely due to serious bugs in Firebug.

Comment: yes, it's a real bug