# Tooltip for interesting/ignored tags in preferences has incorrect description

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tooltips, preferences

Whilst trying to debug [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14805/ignored-tags-get-randomly-concateneted), I've noticed something slightly odd.

If you go into preferences and add an interesting or ignored tag, then hover over it, the tooltip will show "click to delete this tag" - even though clicking *at that point* will actually view the questions associated with the tag. It's only the "x" (which has an accurate tooltip) which deletes the tag from the list.

Comment: It's interesting that the tooltip for new tags is "click to delete this tag" but the one for the "x" is "remove this tag".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the tooltips! Probably over a year ago, but sometimes we forget to update meta.

Answer (score 1):

Good catch. I wonder if that is a possible left-over of a long past time when actually clicking on the tag would remove it from the list or whether it is just a casual mistake.

Comment: No idea - but the nice thing about this bug is it's likely to take less time to fix than it took me to describe :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Are you sure about that?